# Most compact way to compare three objects for equality using Java?

Tags: java, equals

What's the most compact code to compare three objects for (semantic) equality using Java? I have a business rule that the objects must be unique i.e. A *is different to B, A is different to C and B is different to C.*

Assume that the objects are all of the same class and have correctly overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods. A slight wrinkle is that object *C* could be `null`—if this is the case then *A* and *B* have to be different to each other.

I have some code but it's a bit workmanlike for my tastes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the OP said `A` and `B` are never null, `C` may be null, use this:

```
if(A.equals(B) || B.equals(C) || A.equals(C))
   // not unique
```

and, as others have already suggested, you can put it in a method for reuse. Or a generic method if you need more reuse ;-)

Note that in Java, a feature of `equals` is that if its argument is `null` it should not throw, but return false.

Comment: You don't need the last term; if A equals B and B equals C, then A must equal C (or the implementation of equals() is buggy).

Comment: @Aaron: it is not `and`, it is `or`. If one term is false, the other term can still be true: `Auto.equals(Bike) or Bike.equals(Car) or Auto.equals(Car)`. First two are false, third is true: it's needed ;-)

Comment: What if A != B and C == null? My reading of the question is that these are unique, but your first answer tests C first and returns "not unique".

Comment: +1 Good reading of the question, I can't say whether that's true or not. My thought was, at first, null is illegal and if so, should be discarded. The second solution, shorter, deals with your scenario correctly. Well spotted!

Comment: A != B and C == null is a valid scenario.

Comment: Thanks John for elaborating, I removed that part from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hmm, it seems kind of obvious now that I see it written out like that!

Comment: Thinking in autos, bikes and cars helped me out. When in the middle of something, you can't always see the forest for the trees :).

Comment: Agreed. I could have nitpicked and pointed out that a Car is a kind of Auto! ;-)

Comment: That was the idea: Car == Auto, hence the series is not unique: the statement in the answer would equal true.

Answer (score 6):

Since I never start a Java project without using [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), try `ObjectUtils.equals` (it's null safe):

```
if (ObjectUtils.equals(a, b) || ObjectUtils.equals(b, c) || ObjectUtils.equals(a, c)) {
  // error condition
}
```

Put that logic in a generic method, and you'll do even better.

While the business logic allows C to be null, in scenarios like this, it's often better to code defensively and assume that either A or B could be null as well.

Comment: Putting the logic into a varargs method seems more useful than a generic method. A varargs method should enable you to compare any number of objects for equality

Answer (score 4):

You can abstract that method in a utilities method like:

```
public boolean allUnique(Object... objs) {
  Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
  for (Object o : objs)
    set.add(o);
  return set.size() == objs.length
}
```

The method may not perform well for small numbers (due to the overhead of creating the `Set` and the varargs array).  However, it grows linearly `O(n)`, and for large values it's better than the quadratic growth of a nested `if` statements.

Comment: As a side note, make sure that the hashcode() is consistent with equals(),

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean areDistinct(Object a, Object b, Object c) {
    return (!a.equals(b) &&
            (c == null || (!c.equals(a) && !c.equals(b))));
}
```

Comment: `!x && !y` is equal to `!(x || y)` (may save you some typing)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your objects implement equals, you can use the Stream API to get a distinct set of values, and if that distinct count is 1, they are all the same.

```
boolean allEqual = Stream.of(obj1, obj2, obj3).distinct().count() == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the apache's `common.lang3.ObjectUtils.equals()` is `@Deprecated`. Use `Objects.equals(aObj,bObj)`. Comparison should be made with `&&` if you want that all 3 objects are the same. Use `||` if you want that just one combination of **a&b, a&c or b&c** is the same.

```
/**
 * Compare 3 objects of the same {@link TYPE}, if they are all equal using {@link Objects#equals(Object, Object)}.
 * 
 * @param aObj the 1st object
 * @param bObj the 2nd object
 * @param cObj the 3th object
 * @param <TYPE> the type of the objects
 * @return true if the are all the same
 */
public static <TYPE> boolean equals(TYPE aObj, TYPE bObj, TYPE cObj) {
    return Objects.equals(aObj, bObj) && Objects.equals(bObj, cObj) && Objects.equals(cObj, aObj);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.test;

public class Equality {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Boolean flag;

        int[] arr={1,1,1,12};
        flag=check_equal(arr);
        System.out.println(flag);
    }

    public static Boolean check_equal(int[] arr){
        Boolean flag=true;

        outerloop:
        for(int i=1; i< arr.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j=1; j< arr.length; j++){
                    if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                        flag=true;
                    }   
                    else{
                        flag=false;
                        break outerloop;
                    }

                }

            }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?